# Why rotate(0deg) matters?

Tags: html, css, css-transforms

Tried to make a circle orbit continually around a radius of 50px with CSS3 animations:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
div {
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    background-color: black;
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-animation-name: example;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 3s;
animation:example 1s infinite linear;
border-radius:50px;
transform-origin:bottom left;
left:50%;
top:50px;
}
@-webkit-keyframes example {
    0%   {transform:rotate(0deg) translateX(50px);}
    100% {transform:rotate(360deg) translateX(50px);}
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div></div>

</body>
</html>
```

The circle only spins when I include rotate(0deg) to my transform in the 0% keyframe. Why is this? Without rotate(0deg):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
div {
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    background-color: black;
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-animation-name: example; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -webkit-animation-duration: 3s; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
animation:example 1s infinite linear;
border-radius:50px;
transform-origin:bottom left;
left:50%;
top:50px;
}

/* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
@-webkit-keyframes example {
    0%   {transform: translateX(50px);}
    100% {transform:rotate(360deg) translateX(50px);}
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The animation interpolates between a source, and a destination value. The default value often is `auto`, and this can't be interpolated.

Comment: Please consider including `@keyframes` as well as `@-webkit-keyframes`. (You won't see the difference on Chrome or Safari, but you might do on Firefox...)

Comment: @Rounin Yes. I removed it because I wanted to spare the trouble of copy pasting for both '@keyframes' and '@-webkit-keyframes'. Because I will modify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keyframes are used to define what parameters are changing and from-to values.
If something is not defined it's not assumed to be 0 but assumed as not part of the sequence.
At the same time some browsers may treat it differently.

Answer (score 1):

The 'from' or '0%' value should always defined, if not user agent will handle it and not Necessarily set it to zero.

> The keyframe selector for a keyframe style rule consists of a comma-separated list of percentage values or the keywords ‘from’ or ‘to’. The selector is used to specify the percentage along the duration of the animation that the keyframe represents. The keyframe itself is specified by the block of property values declared on the selector. The keyword ‘from’ is equivalent to the value ‘0%’. The keyword ‘to’ is equivalent to the value ‘100%’. Note that the percentage unit specifier must be used on percentage values. Therefore, ‘0’ is an invalid keyframe selector.
>
> **If a ‘0%’ or ‘from’ keyframe is not specified, then the user agent constructs a ‘0%’ keyframe using the computed values of the properties being animated.** If a ‘100%’ or ‘to’ keyframe is not specified, then the user agent constructs a ‘100%’ keyframe using the computed values of the properties being animated. If a keyframe selector specifies negative percentage values or values higher than 100%, then the keyframe will be ignored.

source: https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-animations/